# Repairing corrupted jpegs

Tags: jpeg, file-format, corrupt

Time ago my external HDD crashed (stopped working completely) and I had to recover the files from another HDD from which they had been erased. Some time later I realized that some of the pictures that had been recovered were corrupted.

I couldnt open those images by means of any image program. When I run the "file" command over the .jpgs I get:

```
DSCN9129.JPG: JPEG image data, EXIF standard 2.2
DSCN9130.JPG: JPEG image data, EXIF standard 2.2
DSCN9131.JPG: JPEG image data, EXIF standard 2.2
DSCN9132.JPG: DOS executable (COM)
DSCN9133.JPG: data
DSCN9134.JPG: data
DSCN9135.JPG: JPEG image data, EXIF standard 2.2
DSCN9136.JPG: data
DSCN9137.JPG: data
DSCN9138.JPG: data
DSCN9139.JPG: data
DSCN9140.JPG: 8086 relocatable (Microsoft)
DSCN9141.JPG: data
DSCN9142.JPG: data
```

There, we can notice that some images are ok, some are not recognized and some others are wrongly interpreted as other kind of files.

I am uploading 2 example images:

http://ul.to/u7emvxp8   ---> DSCN9133.JPG   (corrupted)
http://ul.to/zegf7q8a   ---> DSCN9131.JPG   (not corrupted)

I used this python code in order to see what's in the file:

```
import sys, os

with open("./images/DSCN9133.JPG", "rb") as f:
        stri=""
        i=0
        byte = f.read(1)
        while byte != "" and i < 1000:
                i=i+1
                stri = stri+" "+hex(ord(byte))
                byte = f.read(1)
        print(stri)
```

I'm printing here the first few bytes of a corrupted and a not corrupted image.

CORRUPTED:

```
0x6b 0xe8 0xf2 0xd6 0x9b 0xba 0x77 0xb4 0x97 0xd1 0x69 0xbb 0x2e 0xe 0xda 0x8d 0x4 0xb7 0x7 0x33 0xb2 0xf2 0x10 0x35 0x58 0x4e 0xa1 0x80 0x4c 0x2b 0x1f 0x8f 0x9 0xd0 0xaf 0x22 0x5 0x2d 0x87 0xab 0x81 0xb0 0x6c 0x7a 0xd8 0x4c 0x7b 0x52 0xf1 0xe9 0xf3 0xe9 0xca 0xa6 0x4 0xcb 0x9c 0x7b 0x64 0x34 0x98 0x46 0x4 0xd1 0xa6 0x30 0x60 0xb5 0xae 0xcb 0xf2 0x56 0xda 0x20 0x15 0xcf 0x7 0x61 0x2c 0xc 0x3f 0x44 0x67 0x49 0x0 0x41 0xfe 0xac 0x4f 0x15 0xcf 0x9d 0x3a 0x6b 0xdb 0x94 0xb5 0x85 0xa 0x4 0x34 0x7d 0xfd 0x9 0xba 0x86 0xec 0x2f 0xe9 0xa9 0xb6 0xaa 0x62 0x80 0xbb 0x43 0x96 0xa1 0x4d 0x54 0xfa 0x1b 0xdf 0x33 0xab 0x93 0x8a 0xd6 0xdc 0x33 0xe1 0x9d 0x91 0x5a 0x4e 0xd0 0xe5 0x6a 0x1c 0x95 0x72 0x53 0x9f 0x27 0x9a 0x1e 0x8f 0x7d 0x1d 0xad 0x34 0x7b 0xf6 0xc8 0xf 0xde 0xe1 0x48 0xa7 0x58 0x52 0x4d 0x16 0x2b 0x53 0x1b 0x2 0x2a 0x93 0xc6 0x7c 0x76 0x3d 0x78 0xca 0xe2 0x90 0xd3 0x55 0xdb 0x32 0x62 0x1d 0x4f 0xd1 0xd1 0xdc 0x13 0xf 0xb6 0x4e 0x4e 0x66
```

NOT CORRUPTED:

```
0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe1 0x8a 0x45 0x45 0x78 0x69 0x66 0x0 0x0 0x49 0x49 0x2a 0x0 0x8 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xb 0x0 0xe 0x1 0x2 0x0 0xb 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x92 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xf 0x1 0x2 0x0 0x6 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xb2 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x10 0x1 0x2 0x0 0x6 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xca 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x12 0x1 0x3 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1a 0x1 0x5 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xd8 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1b 0x1 0x5 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xe0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x28 0x1 0x3 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x31 0x1 0x2 0x0 0xa 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xe8 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x32 0x1 0x2 0x0 0x14 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x8 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x13 0x2 0x3 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x69 0x87 0x4 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1c 0x1 0x0 0x0 0xa4 0x3 0x0 0x0 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x4e 0x49 0x4b 0x4f 0x4e 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x45 0x33 0x37 0x30 0x30 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x2c 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x2c
```

but I don't know what jpgs are made of...

Can someone give me a piece of advice the direction I should follow in order to find out whether it is possible to repair the images or not?

How can I tell if the pixel information is there or I've just been keeping random data?

I think that knowing the size of the images is a good thing, but of course since these images are compressed it won't be that easy.

EDIT: I found this http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf that should be useful for this, but I also would like to know how can I tell if the pixel data is there or not.

EDIT2: My original question was focused on the following point (I clarify because I realized it wasn't clear enough) I think that it is possible that the bytes on those images are part of jpegs. It can be that the bytes are just shifted or the header is missing, and maybe there is a way to explore whether the data is there. Of course if these were BMPs or uncompressed images of some king this could be the case. Being jpgs, that are compressed I think makes everything way more difficult of not completely impossible. But still, I wonder more in general, if i told someone that among certain bunch of bytes there are the pixel information from an image, how could we proceed?

Answer (score 5):

Here is your entire problem: "I had to recover the files from another HDD from which they had been erased"

When any file is created, the OS (often-usually) writes the data across multiple blocks, and pointers to these blocks are placed in an index file. When a file gets deleted, these indexes and the blocks they point to are marked as "free" (as in "areas of the disk which are now open to storing data").

It's IMPORTANT to understand that the deleted file STILL REMAINS ON THE DISK, and ONLY THE POINTER IS REWRITTEN.

This, of course, is exactly how data recovery works. The recovery program scans the "deleted" portions of a disk looking for recognizable data. When it finds something, it saves that data in various ways, and usually makes an assessment as to whether the discovered data is actually "recoverable" or not.

One method of data identification is by "magic numbers", AKA "file signatures". In the case of JPG files, the magic numbers for the beginning and end of file are: 0xFFD8 and 0xFFD9 respectively.

If you look at your posted data, you'll see that the "not corrupted" file does indeed start with "0xFFD8", and a recovery program would tag it as a JPG file.

HOWEVER...when a file has been deleted, as I said earlier, its data blocks are "free" for the OS to write new user data, overwriting the old data. This often results in say "xyz.jpg" originally spanning 3 blocks before being deleted. You continue using your computer, and at some point part of a letter to aunt mabel gets written to one of those blocks, and only the other 2 blocks of the original xyz.jpg can be recovered (and even then, there are many reasons that the recovery program may only find ONE of those blocks and not both)

OTOH, a recovery program mat also recover an index pointer, and grab whatever is there. So if the recovered file pointer says "DSCN9132.JPG" resides at such-and-such an address, the recovery program will grab the data block, NAME it as "DSCN9132.JPG", but IDENTIFY the data type as a "DOS executable (COM)" file - because that's the type of file that is now physically there as a result of being overwritten. This is one reason for getting the described result as shown in your list example.

And BTW, another result of recovering image files comes when using a graphics program to look at the  JPG files that you see in a recovery directory: Some of the images will look just great, some will have the bottom half ("half" being subjective: it could be a few lines at the bottom to almost the entire image) of the image missing, and some will produce a file error.

This is not an exhaustive or well written treatise on file deletion, recovery or corruption, but I figured your question deserved some kind of an answer, and I hope it gives you some clue as to how these systems work.